# How to run servlet program in linux 12.04

Tags: jsp, servlets

how to configure and run servlet program in linux please any one give me some tips. I have install tomcat 6 and jdk 7.it have var/www directory when i put my servlet file inside directory then it is showing as source code but jsp file is working in this directory when i am put inside my servlet file /usr/share/tomcat6-root then i am getting /url not found   also i am not able to run  given all these program inside that directory /usr/share/tomcat6-examples/examples .please help me.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
      class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet
         {
        private String message;
         public void init() throws ServletException
         {
        message="Hello World";
         }
                public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws               ServletException, IOException
          {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
           out.println("<h1>"+message+"</h1>");
            }
           public void destroy()
        {
         }
         }
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What error message did you get? How does your example looks like (source code?)? Have you installed a Java runtime?